# using VBA Macro in Excel , reseting variable will reset cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to concatenate cells with bold text in one cell.

```
Sub question_concat()

Dim s1 As String
Dim first As Boolean
Dim r As Long

r = 1
For Each c In Selection
    If c.Font.Bold = True Then
        If first = True Then
            r = c.Row
            first = False
        End If
        s1 = s1 & c.Value
    Else
        Cells(r, 3).Value2 = s1
        first = True
        s1 = ""
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

At first it sets value of 3rd column equal to s1, but after clearing s1 for next loop `s1 = ""` , value of cell also clears.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't test if the row is different from the one you stocked at first.

So, if you encounter 2 non-bold cell, it'll :

- write the value of what was found previously and reset `s1`
- write `s1` that has already been reset!

This should be better, even if I personally would rather go with a regular `For` loop to have more control on the way I'd go through the range! ;)

```
Sub question_concat()
Dim s1 As String
Dim first As Boolean
Dim r As Long

r = 1
first = True

For Each c In Selection
    If c.Font.Bold = True Then
        If first = True Then
           r = c.Row
           first = False
        End If
        s1 = s1 & c.Value
    Else
        If r <> c.Row Then
            Cells(r, 3).Value2 = s1
            first = True
            s1 = ""
        End If
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

With a regular `For` loop, like I suggested :

```
Sub question_concat()
Dim s1 As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Rg As Range

Set Rg = Selection

For i = 1 To Rg.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Rg.Columns.Count
        Set c = Rg.Cells(i, j)
        If c.Font.Bold = True Then
            s1 = s1 & c.Value
        Else
        End If
    Next j
    Cells(i, 3).Value2 = s1
    s1 = vbNullString
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I really do not know what are you trying to achieve, but I think that `Dim first As Boolean : first=True` would help you.

Comment: @Vityata : Yup, indeed, it needs to be initialized! Thx for pointing it out!

Comment: the problem is when i assign s1 to a cell, it show the text on cell. but after resetting s1 (s1="") the value of that cell disappears.

Comment: @Farhad : I don't understand... It is what is supposed to happen, what do you want it to do?

Comment: ' Dim S as String'
'S="something"
' Cell(0,1).Value=S'
'S="new"'
this code shows "new" on cell, but i want to show "something", how could i do that?

Comment: @Farhad : Try the second code! ;) better to have control on the way you go through the range! ;)

Comment: still no luck, it doesn't do any concatenate. that's what i need in first place.
by the way, thank you.

Comment: @Farhad : Did you select the range you wanted to concatenate??? Is there bold cells in that selection? Because I can't see how that code doesn't concatenate!